# Editing Woocommerce search form query excluding a category

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce

Iam trying to make a custom search based on woocommerce that will have 2 options available for the user.

First option will be search on certain category called "Vivlia".
Second option will be search on all other categories excluding "Vivlia" category from the results.

Below code is inserted on functions.php file and is called with a shortcode from elementor page.

First option works fine.
Second option though doesnt get any results, even if there should be.

```
function woocommerce_product_search_form_with_categories() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <form role="search" method="get" class="woocommerce-product-search" action="https://e-bibliagora.gr/" target="_self">
        <div class="search-container">
            <input type="search" id="woocommerce-product-search-field-0" class="search-field" placeholder="Αναζήτηση προϊόντων…" autocomplete="off" value="" name="s">
            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
            <?php
            $parent_categories = get_terms( array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'hide_empty' => false,
                'parent' => 0,
            ) );

            if ( ! empty( $parent_categories ) && ! is_wp_error( $parent_categories ) ) {
                echo '<select name="product_cat">';
                echo '<option value="vivlia">Βιβλία</option>'; // Option for Books category
                echo '<option value="all">Όλες οι άλλες κατηγορίες</option>'; // Option for all other categories
                echo '</select>';
            }
            ?>
            <button type="submit" value="Αναζήτηση" class="search-button"></button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('custom_search', 'woocommerce_product_search_form_with_categories');

// Modify product category search query
function modify_product_category_search_query($query) {
    if (isset($_GET['product_cat'])) {
        $product_cat = sanitize_text_field($_GET['product_cat']);

        if ($product_cat === 'vivlia') {
            $query->set('tax_query', array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'vivlia',
                ),
            ));
        } elseif ($product_cat === 'all') {
            $query->set('tax_query', array(
           array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'vivlia',
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                ),
                ),
            );
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'modify_product_category_search_query');
```

Please tell me if you have any questions about the code.